# Trouble compiling Windows DLL using Golang 1.10

Tags: windows, go, dll, compilation

I'm having issues building a Windows DLL in Golang 1.10, which is supported in this latest version:

"The various build modes have been ported to more systems. Specifically, c-shared now works on linux/ppc64le, windows/386, and windows/amd64;" (Source: https://golang.org/doc/go1.10)

I have a very simple program right now (`main.go`) that only exports one function "Test", but am having issues when using the following "go build" command: `env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -buildmode=c-shared main.go`

Specifically, receiving the `can't load package: package main: build constraints exclude all Go files in [PATH]` error. The source code for `main.go` is shown below:

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("from main")
}

//export Test
func Test() string {
    return "this is a test"
}
```

I've never encountered this error before and building without specifying `GOOS` and `GOARCH` works. Hoping someone has encountered this issue and can help me out.

Comment: Is cgo enabled? Do you have the C compiler installed?

Comment: Apologies for my noob-ness in Golang. I added in the `CGO_ENABLED=1` option, which should enable CGO. The new command is `env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -buildmode=c-shared main.go`, but now I'm receiving `gcc_libinit_windows.c:7:10: fatal error: 'windows.h' file not found`. I'm compiling on OSX if that helps.

Comment: If you're compiling on osx, do you have a complete C compiler toolchain installed for windows?

Comment: Ideally I want this to be compiled on an Ubuntu system, which should have gcc installed. Trying to build on Ubuntu gives the following error: `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthreads’; did you mean ‘-pthread’?` Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Having gcc installed doesn't mean you can compile for windows. You need a windows compiler and all the required headers. IIRC for windows the supported compiler is mingw.

Comment: JimB, you are the man! What ended up working:

1. Install mingw on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64-i686` and `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64`
2. Compile for Windows on Ubuntu: `env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -buildmode=c-shared -o main.dll main.go` and `env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -buildmode=c-shared -o main.dll main.go`
3. Verify everything works with `rundll32.exe main.dll,Test`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

1. Make sure you have MinGW installed on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64-i686` and `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64`
2. Compile using the following commands: `GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -buildmode=c-shared -o main.dll main.go` and `GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -buildmode=c-shared -o main.dll main.go`
3. Verify generated DLL works by testing the "Test" export: `rundll32.exe main.dll,Test`

Comment: I wonder why do you have all these `env` spilled around; should work fine without them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do the same in rhel ?

Comment: I was working on a fyne application and had a lot of trable configuring this is ubuntu for 32bit windows. I was using a Makefile to build the exe by adding ```CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc``` it finally worked, thank you :)