# golang cgo - Using linux to cross compile a shared object for darwin

Tags: linux, go, shared-libraries, darwin

The following post details how to use Ubuntu/Linux to cross-compiile a golang c-shared object for Windows:

[Trouble compiling Windows DLL using Golang 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078510/trouble-compiling-windows-dll-using-golang-1-10)

The solution seems to just ensure that mingw is installed and then specifies these two environment variables:

GOOS=windows CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc

Now I would like to do the same thing to build a shared object for Mac/Darwin from Ubuntu. I know that I can set the GOOS=Darwin, but what should be the correct CC/gcc to use? When I do not specify the CC env variable I receive the following error from the go build with GOOS=darwin set:

```
/home/user/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find 1144: No such file or directory
/tmp/go-link-601074638/go.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```